# Writing a JQuery/Javascript fading function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write one function that will be able to fade in/out images inside multiple divs on a single HTML page.  The images in the Divs would need to fade in at the same times from each div.  Then fade out followed by the next image in the div.  Sort of creating a mini image rotation presentation in each div.

I cannot wrap my head around this :)  I can easily make this happen without a function on a page, however, I want something that I can easily repeat with as many div's on the page as I desire.  Can someone please educate me :)  Thanks in advance for any suggestions, I have not been able to find this online.

EXAMPLE

```
function imageRotationFunction(var1, var2, var3) {
   //logic I need help with
}
```

.

```
imageRotationFunction(<array of ID's to fade>, <number of seconds to fade in>, <number of seconds between fades>);
```

HTML PAGE HAS:

```
<div id='fadein0'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='someimage0.png'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='someimage1.png'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='someimage2.png'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='someimage3.png'>
</div>

<div id='fadein1'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='otherimage0.png'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='otherimage1.png'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='otherimage2.png'>
  <img class='imageRotation' src='otherimage3.png'>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're wanting us to write you a custom slider plugin?

Comment: If these help [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569879/create-an-animation-sequence-loop-jquery/12570261#12570261) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232007/making-a-jquery-shuffle-gallery/12232324#12232324).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="fadebox">
  <img src="image0.png" />
  <img src="image1.png" />
  <img src="image2.png" />
  <img src="image3.png" />
</div>
<div class="fadebox">
  <img src="image0.png" />
  <img src="image1.png" />
  <img src="image2.png" />
  <img src="image3.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fadebox {
    position:relative;
}
.fadebox>img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear;
}
.fadebox>img:first-child {
    position:static;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".fadebox"), l = divs.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        (function(div) {
            var imgs = div.children, l = imgs.length, i = -1,
                step = function() {
                    if(i > -1) imgs[i].style.opacity = 0;
                    i = (i+1)%l;
                    imgs[i].style.opacity = 1;
                };
            step();
            setInterval(step,5000);
        })(divs[i]);
    }
})();
```

In the above, `1s` is the time it takes for the fade to happen, and `5000` is the number of milliseconds the between fades (including the transition, so in this case the image will stay displayed for 4 seconds)

Note that this only works in supporting browsers, like so:

- IE, Chrome and Firefox should work just fine in their latest versions
- IE9 works, but don't fade between images
- IE8 and below don't work due to not supporting `opacity`
- IE7 and below don't work due to not supporting `querySelectorAll`

The last two cases can be fixed by adding a suitable `filter` style (IE8) and shimming `querySelectorAll` (IE7 and below)